# IntelliJ Gradle plugin refreshes all projects when I requested only a sub project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to figure out how to use IntelliJ's Gradle plugin to update a single change from build.gradle into my project without having to refresh the entire Gradle project.

Let's say I've added a new `compile dependency`. But IntelliJ won't know about the new dependency yet until I refresh Gradle.

I went into Views -> Gradle -> And refreshed the single gradle module.

IntelliJ's Gradle plugin now proceeds to refresh *Every* gradle project in my entire build.gradle file.

Why is it doing that? How can I fix it?

Comment: yeah different wording but same question for sure thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCoder do you have an epic for better support for large monolithic build.gradle files that I can vote on?